# Ember "Action passed is null or undefined in (action)" error

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember component `checkout-form` that contains some logic for handling a checkout process. Here’s a simplified version of how I’m using it:

```
{{#checkout-form}}

  {{#each model.courses.otherDates as |date|}}
    {{course-date model=date selectDate=(action selectDate) }}
  {{/each}}

{{/checkout-form}}
```

Inside of my `checkout-form.js` component I have the following action:

```
selectDate(day) {
  this.set("startAt", day.get("serverString"))
}
```

And finally inside of my `course-date.js` component I have:

```
click () {
  const courseStart = this.get('courseStart')
  this.get('selectDate')(courseStart)
}
```

However, when running this code I get the error:

```
ember.debug.js:19818 Assertion Failed: Action passed is null or undefined in (action) from <site@controller:checkout/date::ember389>.
```

What am I missing here? I am passing the action into the `course-date` component and not sure why is it asking for a controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reason for the error is,
You are accessing `selectDate` which is undefined in that scope(ie., controller) If you do `{{log 'selectDate value is ' selectDate}}` inside that checkout-form which will print  `selectDate value is undefined`. so if you want to access any properties, actions which are defined in the component then that component should yield those values.

Here is [twiddle which demonstrates](https://ember-twiddle.com/fa902a7ea9295ca4dfe4bd5cf07763cb?openFiles=templates.components.checkout-form.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.course-date.hbs) how you can yield action from component.

application.hbs

```
{{#checkout-form as |selectDate| }}
 {{!-- 
 here context is controller not the checkout-form component
 Whatever you want to access from component, then component should yield those values.
 --}}
 {{course-date selectDate=(action 'selectDateInController')}}
 {{course-date selectDate=selectDate}}
{{/checkout-form}}
```

application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',
  actions:{
    selectDateInController(){
      console.log(' selectDate in controller');
    }
  }
});
```

templates/components/checkout-form.hbs - Here we are yielding `selectDate` action

```
{{yield (action 'selectDate')}}
```

components/checkout-form.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
   actions:{
    selectDate(){
      console.log(' selectDate in checkout-form component');
    }
  }
});
```

course-date.hbs - Here we are just using the closure action that is passed to this component.

```
<button {{action selectDate}}> CourseDate </button>
```

Comment: `{{yield (action 'selectDate')}}` does the trick perfectly. Thank you!